# Joomla RSFORM Hide/Show field to specific usergroup?

Tags: joomla

I have a long RSFORM which need to be filled by several users.

I have 2 joomla usergroups: Boss & Worker

Boss need to see all the fields of the form
I don't want Worker see all the fields.
How can I hide fields to specific users or group of users?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to modify your site's template, adding a class based on the user's group, and then use CSS to manipulate the front end display of the forms.

Start by saving a backup of your template's index.php file

(1) Somewhere near the top of index.php you want to add

```
<?php
    $user =& JFactory::getUser();
?>
```

Check how your template file is structured and add this where it makes sense.

(2) Then modify the body tag with something like

```
<body  class="<?php
    foreach ($user->groups as $key => $value){
             echo ' group'.$key;
        }
    ?>
">
```

The result of (1) and (2) is that the body tag will have a nuber of classes based on the user's groups, eg  `<body class="group2 group5 >`  . These group IDs will correspond to what you see in the backend under Users > Groups  > ID

Let's say Boss is ID 2 and Worker is ID 3.

(3) RSJoomla wraps each label and form field in a div, and we'll use its class name to target and hide the field. Use web inspector to examine your form and find the class names of this wrapper, eg

```
<div class="rsform-block rsform-block-fieldname"> ...</div>
```

Lastly, you need to add some simple CSS rules to hide this field from Workers

(4) From RSJoomla > Form > Form Properties > CSS & Javascript, add

```
<style>  
 /* if this user belongs to group3 (ie worker) hide rsform-block-fieldname  */
 .group3 .rsform-block-fieldname{display:none;}
</style>
```

Depending on the specifics of your template and form you might need to tweak this suggestion a bit, let me know if you need any more help.

Good luck!